# Implement settings, common practice?

Tags: c++, qt

Assume I save my settings of a widget with `QSettings`. How is `QSettings` meant to be used? As a member of my widget, accessed everytime one of the settings is used, or created and used once on widget construction and destruction?

Somehow the first is pretty practical, since it makes settings globally available - handy if you have a settingsdialog. On the other side I ask myself if the access to the settings is efficient, if you need them a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`QSettings` uses a form of global cache to actually hold the saved data, called a `QConfFile`, it's a part of the private API.  It doesn't actually read the settings straight from disk (well that's not quite true, it `sync()`s at construction, destruction, and at regular intervals).

So calling `value(..)` is fairly cheap, on a par with reading from a `QMap`. I'd use `QSettings` wherever it is needed.